# Wordpress menu with | inbetween

Tags: php, wordpress

A simple one i'm sure but I cannot figure this out.

When i use the standard wordpress menu, how do I put in a separator

i.e. Home | About Us | Contact Us

All I get at the moment is Home About Us Contact Us and their seems to be no way of putting | in?

Comment: Apply css border right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you to it using `Css` Trick.

```
.nav li + li:before{
    content: " | ";
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

WordPress way:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu('menu=Top Menu&after=<span class="menu-divider">|</span>'); ?>
```

**Note:** Change class as per your html in style above.

Comment: Thanks Rikesh, the wordpress way worked a treat, only issue is the last menu item has | after it, i know it's something todo with ul li:last-child a but can't figure it out

Comment: Check my updated answer & add `span.menu-divider:last-child {display:none;}` in your style.

Comment: Hi Rikesh, that didn't work but it put me on the right track, here's what i used #top-elements ul li:last-child span {
 display: none;
} thanks